# How to solve Statement List Tester Error?

Tags: android, applinks

When i enter all the required info in [Statement List Generator and Tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) and say Test statement its giving following error :

> No app deep linking permission found for {App package name} at {Hosting site domain}

I am facing problem of opening browser applications along with my desired app with App link.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No, i used web view instead.